# Dash share fig object between callbacks

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'd like to use the `fig.update_layout` method in a callback, my current program looks like this:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id="sensor-graph",
        config={
            'modeBarButtonsToAdd': [
                "drawrect",
                "eraseshape"
            ]
        },
        style={"display": "none"}
    ),
    html.Button('Occupancy', id="occupancy", n_clicks=0, style={'font-size': '12px', 'width': '140px', 'height':'37px', "background-color": "#7FFFD4"}),
])
```

and I create the figure for my `dcc-graph` dynamically in a callback with `Output('sensor-graph', 'figure')`. I want to be able to label areas with different colors in the `sensor-graph` with the `drawrect` functionally dash has. But to change colors when I click the `Occupancy` Button I need access to the fig attribute to call `fig.update_layout`, if I just return a new figure the plot will redraw (which is not an option because the graphs take multiple seconds to redraw).
I tried it like this (also changes the button style):

```
@app.callback(
    [Output("occupancy", "style"), Output("occupancy", "children")],
    Input("occupancy", "n_clicks"),
    [State('sensor-graph', 'figure'), State('occupancy', 'children')]
)
def change_color(_, fig, curr_name):
        fig.update_layout({
            "fillcolor": "green" if curr_name == "No Occupancy" else "red"
        })
        return {"background-color": "#7FFFD4" if curr_name == "No Occupancy" else "#F08080"}, "Occupancy" if curr_name == "No Occupancy" else "No Occupancy"
```

But I get the following error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'update_layout'` because Dash returns the figure dict not a `go.Figure` object with which I could use the `update_layout` methode.
So my question is: How can I share the `go.Figure` object between callback functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reproduce a `plotly.graph_objects.Figure` from that particular dictionary, you call `figure = plotly.graph_objects.Figure(fig)` in the callback.

Comment: My god thanks so much, I was about to give up on dash / plotly <3

Comment: You're welcome :) It's a really good tool don't give up on it yet!

Comment: Could you elaborate on your solution @DanielAlMouiee or @paulmüller? If I generate a figure in my callback function with `figure = plotly.graph_objects.Figure(fig)` as you suggest, how do I pass it back to the Graph component?

Comment: @darudiith, you can pass in `Input('dcc-graph-id', 'figure')` as an input, then call `figure = plotly.graph_objects.Figure(fig)` to reproduce the graph in your callback function, then if you want to pass it back to the figure, use `Output('dcc-graph-id', 'figure')` and return a graph of type identical to the `figure` variable I mentioned.

Comment: I did this, but it turns out that changing the xbins dictionary parameter of a histogram figure through update_traces does not trigger a recalculation of the histogram bins, which I was trying to achieve. So I can pass it back and forth, but not update every aspect.

Comment: hi @DanielAlMouiee wouldn't your Input/Output raise a duplicate output error? I mean, as I understand, the figure already exists, as Output of another callback. Would you mind guys provide a toy example? Thanks

Comment: Hi @GabrielePompa, my suggestion was to use the existing input `Figure` component that is passed in to create a new instance of `plotly.graph_objects.Figure` within the callback (answering the question at the end "So my question is: How can I share the go.Figure object between callback functions?" 

You are also right, if we were to call fig.update_layout in this callback then we'll need to return it and that won't be possible since another callback is already utilizing that output. The best way would be to combine both functionalities into a single callback with uses the same Figure output.